# How to reformat words in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In cell A1, it says "269 Southwest 13th Avenue, Pompano Beach, FL".

In cell A2, I want it to be reformatted to "Pompano Beach, FL; 269 Southwest 13th Avenue".

What formula would I use to reformat?

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: there is a bunch of text manipulation formulas in excel. (Formula -> function library -> text functions). You'll have to combine several of these functions to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### LEFT & RIGHT Approach

This approach uses the LEFT and RIGHT functions to find the two text strings.  TRIM removes any trailing and following white spaces.

```
=TRIM( RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1)) & ";" & " " & 
       LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1) )
```

##### INDEX & TEXTSPLIT Approach

This approach uses TEXTSPLIT to separate the string based on commas, then uses INDEX to select the component parts for joining with `&`.  TRIM removes any trailing and following white spaces.

```
=TRIM( INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1, ","),, 2) & ", " & 
       INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1, ","),, 3) & "; " &
       INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1, ","),, 1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no version constraints based on your tags:

```
=TRIM(TEXTJOIN("; ",,TEXTAFTER(A1,","),TEXTBEFORE(A1,",")))
```

[image]